# Script for checking if the created AMI is available or not,

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, scripting

I am trying to write a script where we take backup of an AMI (Amazon Machine Image) & once its completed & it's status shows 'Available' than it email us informing the same.

I have got the first part covered but having problem with second part i.e. to check continuously for the when the image is available & email us. To check the status as available, i am using the following command,

```
/usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids=$AMI_ID --query "Images[*].{st:State}" |  grep -e "available" | wc -l'
```

This will return output as 1 when AMI is available  but having trouble in creating a loop which runs the above command continuously to check the output is equal to 1 or not.

Please help in figuring out this loop.

PS IMAGE creation takes anywhere from 10 to 30 minutes or even more in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an infinite loop

```
while true
   do
       if /usr/bin/aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids=$AMI_ID --query "Images[*].{st:State}" |  grep -e "available" | wc -l'; then
          break
       fi
   esac
done
```

Comment: what if the image never got made & than we will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Add a timeout to it

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below as well:  [Update sleepTime as needed]

Notice I've added flag `--executable-users self` to your command to list the images available for you.

```
sleepTime=60 # sleepTime in seconds
while true ; do
  count=$(aws ec2 describe-images --executable-users self --query "Images[*].{st:State}" |  grep -e "available" | wc -l)
  if [[ $count == 1 ]] ; then
     echo "Image is ready... Add your emailing code here"
     exit 0
  fi
  sleep $sleepTime;
  printf "." 
done
```

Comment: Remove the triple backticks and add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line of code, and your script will be much easier to read.

Comment: Formatted as suggested. Looks good now. Thanks @Michael-sqlbot.

Comment: Sorry did not respond for so long, this worked as i needed it to be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [AWS Image-Exists Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/image-exists.html)
could include the following the following code in the script:

```
aws ec2 wait image-exists \
--image-ids ami-0abcdef1234567890
```

(replace ami-0abcdef1234567890 with seeked AMI code)

According to documentation, image-exists has no output, but when found, wait will continue the script.